# Reassigning constants when creating wrapper library in Go

Tags: go, wrapper, lib

So I want to create my own wrapper library from already existing lib A.
Library A has some functions and also some constants, example:

```
package lib


const(
   HeaderA = "headerA"
   HeaderB = "headerB"
)

func doWork(string header) {
   // some work
}
```

Now the question is: Do I have to reassign these constants in my own library ?

```
package mylib
const (
    myHeaderA = lib.HeaderA
    myHeaderB = lib.HeaderB
)
```

What is the best practice in this case ? It seems ok to reassign them in order to make the user unaware of lib A, but what if this library has a ton of constants ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you "have" to?  Well, that depends on how you want your package to work. If your real question is "Is there an automatic way to do this?" The answer is no.  In theory, it could be done with some code generation, but I'm not aware of any tools that do that, and asking for such a tool would be off-topic, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "package embedding", so constants from `lib` will not magically appear to be constants of `mylib`. If you want to provide those same constants in `mylib`, yes, you have to provide (copy) all those.

> but what if this library has a ton of constants ?

Then on your mission to provide a wrapper for such a library that has a ton of constants, you also have to provide a ton of constants yourself (if the users of `mylib` do need all those constants).

If you want to mimic the complete functionality of `lib`, that raises the question whether you really need this, and wouldn't it be simpler to just use `lib` instead of `mylib`.

Note that you may create a utility that would generate a `.go` source file for `mylib` that would "copy" all exported constants of `lib`. Check out the [`go/parser`](https://golang.org/pkg/go/parser/) package for a starting point.